# align caption with slider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/59/

html:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="example">
            <div id="slides" style="width:1000px;height:430px;"></div>
                <div id="" class="" style="position:relative; width:970px; margin:auto;" align="">
                    <div id="crossSlideCaption" class="caption">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(function() {
        $('#slides').crossSlide({
            speed: 40,
            fade: 1
        }, [
            { src: 'img/photo-2.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'Our Business is to Encrypt and Secure Your Communications', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-10.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The Solution for Secured Communications and Privacy.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-3.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'All Text and Phone Communications are Encrypted End-to-End.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-4.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'Secured Communications for Law Enforcement and Public Officials.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-5.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'Secured Communications for the U.S. Military.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-6.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The World Leader in Encrypted Communications.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-7.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The Solution for Corporate Executives, Law Enforcement, Homeland Security, Goverment Agencies and more...', href: '#'  }

        /*  */
        ], function(idx, img, idxOut, imgOut) {
            if (idxOut == undefined) {
                if(idx == 0 || idx == 3 || idx == 6 || idx == 9){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '0px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginBottom = '-85px';
                }else if(idx == 1 || idx == 4 || idx == 7 || idx == 10 || idx == 12){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '280px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginBottom = '-100px';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-52px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginBottom = '-485px';
                };
                $('div.caption').text(img.alt).animate({ opacity: 1.0 })
            } else {
                $('div.caption').animate({ opacity: 0 })
            }});
        $('div.caption').show().css({ opacity: 0 })
    });
```

Everything works fine, except caption.

So, I tried with this code,

```
function(idx, img, idxOut, imgOut) {
            if (idxOut == undefined) {
                if(idx == 0 || idx == 3 || idx == 6 || idx == 9){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '0px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginBottom = '-85px';
                }else if(idx == 1 || idx == 4 || idx == 7 || idx == 10 || idx == 12){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '280px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginBottom = '-100px';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-52px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginBottom = '-485px';
                };
```

But, still it is not working, I need something like this http://securedcommunications.com/

That is,

when first slide -> caption will be on top of slide

2nd slide --> middle

3rd slide -->bottom.[repeatedly].

Can anyone help me with exact solution for this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put following code and try:

Style:

```
#crossSlideCaption{
z-index:999 !important;
position:relative !important;    
}
```

Script:

```
if(idx == 0 || idx == 3 || idx == 6 || idx == 9){   
$('#crossSlideCaption').css("top","20px");
$('#crossSlideCaption').css("left","0px");
}
```

and similarly to all other condition.

Here is [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/62/)

Comment: In your fiddle,but third one is not in bottom right?

Comment: Third sliders was not in the code. I just added it. You can see the updated fiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/63/)

Comment: And , If i have long text character means, need to show like this,http://postimg.org/image/qe7diz4qn/... but for me,, it shows single line only..may i know how to do that

Comment: You can simply add text-align center and width to that particular caption condition like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/64/)

Answer (score 0):

remove margin-left to none

```
document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-485px';

document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-100px';
```

here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/3jcgfhec/